# 'init()' is deprecated: Use init(configuration:) instead and handle errors appropriately

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

I am writing a code for a Sentiment Analysis using Swift, but I get this error

> ('init()' is deprecated: Use init(configuration:) instead and handle errors appropriately.),

when writing this line of code:

```
let model = SentimentsClassifier_1()
```

Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?
Thanks!

Don't know how to solve this yet...

Comment: This is not an error. It's a warning which tells you to use the `throw`ing API `init(configuration:) `

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.